Algebraic varieties forming a group but with more periods than elliptic curve
An elliptic curve is known to be isomorphic to a "complex torus" with two periods. Points on an elliptic curve follow a group law and can be parametrized by two basis vectors on that complex torus.
Are there other well-known algebraic varieties that form a group law just as elliptic curves do, but with a basis of more dimensions?

Yes, the complex points of an abelian variety form a complex torus, and abelian varieties are proper, geometrically integral group varieties, hence have group laws. In particular, the Jacobian variety of a genus $g$ curve is a $g$-dimensional abelian variety.

Yes, the complex points of an abelian variety form a complex torus. An abelian variety is a proper, geometrically integral group variety, hence has a group law. In particular, the Jacobian variety of a genus $g$ curve is a $g$-dimensional abelian variety.
